# How to remove NPAPI plugins from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, npapi

How do i remove an NPAPI plugin from Chrome?

---

For example:

- if i wanted to see how Google Maps behaves if i don't have the **Earth** Plugin available, and contrast it to how it behaves when it's available again
- if i wanted to see how Youtube behaves if i don't have the **Flash** plugin available, and contrast it to how it behaves when it's available again
- if i wanted to see how a PDF behaves if i don't have the **Adobe PDF** plugin available, and contrast it to how it behaves when it's available again
- if i watned to see how a silverlight page behaves if i don't have the **Silverlight** plugin avalable, and contrast it to how it behaves when it's available again

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit `about:plugins`, disable or enable the plugins based on what you want.

Comment: Note that this will enable/disable, not remove. Removing it depends on how it's installed; it could be part of an extension, in which case you'd need to remove the extension. It could be in the plugins directory in your chrome installation, in which case you need to delete it.  It could be registered in the windows registry under HKLM/Software/MozillaPlugins or HKCU/Software/MozillaPlugins in which case deleting the registry key should do it.

Comment: @taxilian, you are right, but it is important to recall, that editing the registry would effect all NPAPI browsers, not just Chrome.

Comment: Very true; I think your solution is the best way to solve the problem, I merely added the comment for completeness.